# Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am generating excel file with dynamic data which having formulas in some cells, When I am opening generated excel file I am getting one popup message from ms excel that:

> Excel was able to open the file  by repairing or removing the
>   unreadable content.
>
> Removed Records: Shared formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
>   Removed Records: Formula from /xl/calcChain.xml part (Calculation
>   properties)

The log generated by ms excel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error120920_01.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\fileName.xlsx'</summary>
-<removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:">
<removedRecord>Removed Records: Shared formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord>
<removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/calcChain.xml part (Calculation properties)</removedRecord>
</removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

I am not able find the exact root cause of this problem.I want to find which cell creating this problem.
lib version : `apache poi 3.11`

Comment: Please try with the latest version 3.13, there were some related bugfixes that might solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In excel template file, on one cell excel formula was set and I was trying to set `XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` and assigning numeric value to it using code.
This was causing the problem to open ms excel file.